# How to create a schema from JSON file using Spark Scala for subset of fields?

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am trying to create a schema of a nested JSON file so that it can become a dataframe.

However, I am not sure if there is way to create a schema without defining all the fields in the JSON file if I only need the 'id' and 'text' from it - a subset.

I am currently doing it using scala in spark shell. As you can see from the file, I downloaded it as part-00000 from HDFS.

[image: Here is my JSON file].

Comment: can you post your schema in json format ? like df.schema.json ?

Comment: nope i am not able too in spark shell. it asked me to infer the schema manually @Srinivas

Comment: Add some sample input data and expected output

Comment: On the question for yall to see or for my actual code? @Srinivas

Comment: if you post some same data in json format we can easily provide better solution for your problem..

Comment: the data that i have is streamed from twitter api and according to twitter website its in json format. so i save the tweet with this command ".saveAsTextFiles("hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/sparkApp/tweets2/","json")" @Srinivas

Comment: ok, first take full schema in json format and then keep required files and remove other fields and apply that schema to your json. check blow post which is similar to what i mentioned here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manuals on JSON:

> Apply the schema using the `.schema` method. This read returns *only*
> the columns specified in the schema.

So you are good to go with what you imply.

E.g.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType};
val schema = new StructType()
      .add("op_ts", StringType, true)

val df = spark.read.schema(schema)
              .option("multiLine", true).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
              .json("/FileStore/tables/json_stuff.txt")
df.printSchema()
df.show(false)
```

returns:

```
root
 |-- op_ts: string (nullable = true)

+--------------------------+
|op_ts                     |
+--------------------------+
|2019-05-31 04:24:34.000327|
+--------------------------+
```

for this schema:

```
root
 |-- after: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- CODE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- CREATED: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ID: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- STATUS: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- UPDATE_TIME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- before: string (nullable = true)
 |-- current_ts: string (nullable = true)
 |-- op_ts: string (nullable = true)
 |-- op_type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- pos: string (nullable = true)
 |-- primary_keys: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- table: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tokens: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- csn: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- txid: string (nullable = true)
```

gotten from same file using:

```
val df = spark.read
              .option("multiLine", true).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
              .json("/FileStore/tables/json_stuff.txt")
df.printSchema()
df.show(false)
```

This latter is just for proof.

Comment: @OoIJac, This solution should solve your problem.. & upvoted for detailed info.. :)

Comment: @Srinivas, can i do this in spark shell? and also, this solution just helped me to define a schema, so is there a way for me to connect the fields from the json file into this self defined schema?

Comment: Simple way is get actual schema from your data and modify or remove columns which are not required. And then use that schema to load same data.

Comment: @Srinivas  I am not sure what you mean, the second part is only to show the overall schema and prove that a subset is also possible with .schema option.

Comment: yes i know what you mean, however i am not able to get my schema from my data cause they ask me to manually infer it @Srinivas

Comment: Then you manually infer it as I show. What is the issue? None. Just do the .schema. But to write that you must know something, you cannot guess.

Comment: I have done it thanks for your help @thebluephantom